# How to insert the values in the gridview without dataset,datatable

Tags: c#

Hai Freinds

I am having two textbox name empame,empid  i n that i am going to enter the values and insert into the grid.its is simple.but here i should not use these Datasoruce,dataset,datatable.datarow.directly if i enter it sholud go and insert in the gridview.

Tx in advance

Comment: without Gridview's Datasoruce i think no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridView can be [bound to any collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx#binding_to_data) that implements `IEnumerable`.

If you don't want to use a DataTable or DataSet you could create an ArrayList and bind the DataGrid to that.